# How to fix Eslint prefer-destructuring

Tags: javascript, eslint, destructuring

How should I rewrite the following line to avoid getting this error

```
ctrl.formData.type = ctrl.types[0];
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty horrible idea to use destructuring here. Just disable the rule.

Comment: `({types: [ctrl.formData.type]} = ctrl);` could do it. Ugh.

Comment: @Bergi I already disabled a few rules, I do not want to end up with eslint installed but all the rules disabled:) Is pretty ugly, but thanks

Comment: You might want to turn off the rule for `AssignmentExpression` only but not for `VariableDeclarator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tweaking the rule configuration based on the [prefer-destructuring docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) ought to avoid this case. This change would disable the rule for assignments like your example while keeping it for the more common case of declarations:

```
"prefer-destructuring": ["error", {
  "AssignmentExpression": {
    "array": false,
    "object": false
  }
}]
```

If you want to keep the rule configured as-is, this one-liner works:

```
[ctrl.formData.type] = ctrl.types;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
let [ type ] = ctrl.types;
ctrl.formData.type = type;
```

More info here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring